# Images in Designer Email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email, image-display

I have a simple requirement to add an image in Designer Email. Which i added by editing the body of email in Designer.
But my problem is that the our sharepoint is not internet hosted and works under client network only but email is obviously hosted on internet.

So the email client is not able to reach image source. Is there a way i could directly embed the image in HTML such that it does not have to reach sharepoint for image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as expected earlier there is now way for this. All i did is hosted my images on the internet.

Comment: You could possible use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures/9110164#9110164 where they encode the image as a base64 string and embedd it in the body

Comment: Though for now my job is done but i will surely try this.

Comment: Hehe, I do not know if it will actually work in a designer email, but it is a pretty appoach :)